# How do you install a thermal fuse in a hairdryer?

Tags: fuses, thermal

Is it possible to manually wrap the thermal fuse's pins around the 'grommets' as shown in the picture?

[image]

The arrows point to the two grommets, with the thermal fuse in the question across the top.

Comment: Those are [eyelet PCB rivets](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/pcb-rivets-riveting-tools/1603313?cm_mmc=IE-PLA-DS3A-_-google-_-CSS_IE_EN_ESD_Control_%26_Cleanroom_%26_PCB_Prototyping_Whoop_HI-_-(IE:Whoop!)+PCB+Rivets+%26+Riveting+Tools-_-1603313&matchtype=&pla-322567939903&gclid=Cj0KCQiAjJOQBhCkARIsAEKMtO24gzOdBsVuMkzzPl8MMZjUrcav8Thum5UyHuHog8BQL3WwXaWRd7waAgsKEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), not [grommets](https://ie.rs-online.com/web/p/cable-grommets/6664590/). Grommets are for protecting cables going through steel panels and are insulating.

Comment: How was the original connected?

Comment: Either spot weld or crimp. You can’t solder it (well, not easily) as you’d need hi temp solder and the act of soldering will cause the fuse to fail.

Comment: yea, saw someone in youtube use 'grommet', and used it for lack of better word/knoledge. btw, the original was wrapped around it by its pins (not sure how tightly or if all around, and if minimal contact would be enough)..

Comment: original was wrapped by its pins around rivets, and had to be pried open. wrapping new one back seems not  possible, due to its pins being not easily bendable..

Answer (score 1):

What temp rating is printed on the thermal fuse (number after TF)? Is it 154C? I have to do the same repair on a Connair 1875 and the thermal fuse is illegible. I'm planning to try to wrap the leads around the existing rivets using needle nose plyers and some persuasion as there is a gap. Note that it's not in the location you are showing. Another option is to use a small diameter bolt and nut through the center of the hollow rivet through a loop bend in the wire. You could also drill it out and use a pop rivet. What you are showing in the picture is the bimetal switch which should also be in the circuit. The thermal fuse is a second line of defense in case the bimetal switch fails to open in an overheat situation.